# Why does Python have __set__ / __get__ and __setattr__ / __getattr__ when it has @property decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am new to Python and trying to get my head around Python OOP.

The "proper" way to do get/set attribute in Python seems to be to use @property and @propertyname.setter decorators.

While I understand the use of @property and @propertyname.setter, the presence of `__set__ / __get__` and `__setattr__ / __getattr__` is confusing me. Why do these even exist if they are not supposed to be used?

I still can't figure out why there are two pairs and not just a pair of `__set__ / __get__`.

Finally, do we use the decorator @property or use method Property()? The Property() method needs one to pass the methods that correspond to the getter, setter and deleter for the property

Comment: Welcome to python. This article will help you understand this: https://realpython.com/python-descriptors/

Comment: Decorators were added to Python more recently than `Property()` and using @property is usually more convenient, but you can call `Property()` at runtime and decorators are declarative and so are fixed. `__getattr__` is lower-level and more general than either.

Comment: The `property` type is an application of the descriptor protocol, which is implemented using `__get__` and `__set__`. The [Descriptor howto guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) includes a pure Python implementation of `property` to demonstrate how it uses the descriptor protocol.

Comment: From what I understand, usually the attributes are looked up in a dictionary which we can access using the __dict__ as well. However, by using the __get__ __set__ or @property, we are basically redefining how the attribute read/write behaviour works. Is this correct understanding?

Comment: (1/2) `__getattr__`/`__setattr__` & `__get__`/`__set__` apply to the entire object but `@property` and `@prop.setter` apply per attribute. So `__getattr__`/`__setter__` would need a long if/else block to get/set different answers for different attributes. But with @property, you return each attribute's value from a single function for that attribute. (Here, I use the word attribute loosely.) With `__get/set__`, you'd need to create a class per descriptor which has a different behaviour - if you have many "properties" which share behaviour and differ only in initial value, that's an advantage.

Comment: (2/2) But if they differ a lot or even a little, it's inconvenient to create classes for each. For the "little differences", if you put them into a single descriptor-implementing-class, then you'd create complex code/branches which make code harder to read & maintain.